# Firefox Thumbnail Plugin

Tags: firefox, plugins, preview

Is there a Firefox plugin that provides the layout of the New Tab Jumpstart plugin, but the flexibility of the Speed Dial plugin?  The layout of the New Tab Jumpstart is nice and simple, but it uses the browser history to determine the content for each preview panel.  I like how you can specify which sites should be in the preview panels for Speed Dial, but its layout is way too cluttered.  I am setting up a computer for an elderly gentlement who is easily confused, so I need a nice simple layout with no clutter.  Is there anything like that?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5721/